# Shell Script not appending, instead it's erasing contents

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh, cat

My goal is to curl my newly created API with a list of usernames in a .txt file, then receive the API response, save it to a .json, then create a .csv in the end (To read it easier).

This is my script:

```
echo "$result" | jq 'del(.id, .Time, .username)' | jq '{andres:[.[]]}' > newresult
```

Input: `sudo bash script.sh usernames.txt`
Usernames.txt:

```
test1
test2
test3
test4
```

Result:

```
"id","username"
4,"test4"
```

Desired Result:

```
"id","username"
1,"test1"
2,"test2"
3,"test3"
4,"test4"
```

It creates the files as required, and even saves the result. However, it only outputs 1 Result. I can open the CSV/Json as it's running, and see it's querying for different Usernames, but then when it starts another query, rather than Appending it all to the same file, it deletes the Newresult, Result.json, Results.csv, and creates new ones, meaning in the end, i only end up with a result of one username, rather than a list of 5 for example. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `>` isn't *expected* to append. Its documentation explicitly says that it truncates.

Comment: ...that said, this code could really stand to be largely rewritten -- doing a whole bunch of in-place operations is really bad form. If you love `jq`, maybe move the logic into just one jq call rather than having so much shell involved? And there's a whole lot in this code like the `cat x | sponge x` that just has no obvious purpose or use whatsoever. See the [mcve] guidelines -- code in a question should be the *shortest possible thing* that lets someone else see the problem at hand when they run it themselves (obviously, someone can't run code that relies on http://example.com/ themselves).

Comment: ...srsly, though -- I see no reason for this code to invoke `jq` more than a single time, doing all the work in that one instance. To actually provide a tested example of that, though, we'd need the API results, which aren't included here (but which -- if it weren't possible to simplify the question to not include any API use at all -- a [mcve] *would* include, perhaps by substituting `curl` with a function that just returns a hardcoded sample document).

Comment: For further guidance on building the shortest possible code that lets someone else reproduce a problem, see the "Tricks for Trimming" section of http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `>>` to append to file. Try:

```
    : >results.csv
    for ligne in $(seq 1 "$nbrlignes");
    do
        ...
        jq -r '
        ["id", "username"] as $headers
            | $headers, (.andres[][] | [.[$headers[]]]) | @csv
        ' < result.json >> results.csv
    done
```

By using `>` you overwrite the file each time the loop runs.
Also your script looks like it should be largely rewritten and simplified.

Comment: Thanks! Worked!

Also, wouldn't know where to begin. It works, if it aint broken, don't fix it!